# FlexGanttFX example code

Tags: java, gantt-chart

Does anyone have an idea(or a small app) showing how does FlexGanttFX work. The 'installation' tab shows a small program to set up the basics on the stage, so does the tutorial. But I was wondering if anyone has used it before and might be willing to share an example here. 
The link to FlexGanttFX : 
https://flexgantt.atlassian.net/wiki/display/FFXMAN/FlexGanttFX+Developer+Manual

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The FlexGanttFX distribution contains a "sampler" app. Each sample has a "Source" tab where you can see how it was done.